# Is it possible to download and install community edition of Palantir Foundy softrware at home?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am required to learn palantir foundy for my job. While i am learning it through the tutorials and from the self guided tours, is there a way to install it on my home pc? Also is there any recommendation on good tutorials for beginners (I will be mostly in dev role, but an understanding of Ontology etc will be good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at the moment no publicly available Foundry instance. Once you get access to Foundry I recommend going through the academy tutorials, those should provide a very good foundation.